# Figaro not creating 'application.yml' file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, figaro-ruby

I'm using figaro to securely store gmail login information.

As far as I can tell, when the gem is installed it is supposed to create an application.yml fil to store this data in.

It is also supposed to add application.yml to the gitignore file.

I've installed this gem and confirmed that it is being used by rails but it has not created the file nor has it added any information to gitignore.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run the installation script?

Comment: yes, I've also checked my gem list and ran bundle install to make sure that the gem was being used. Figaro is listed as present in the app and as being used by the app. I've searched the internet to see if anyone else has had this issue and found nothing so far.

Comment: You ran `$ bundle exec figaro install`? What was the console output?

Comment: Ok well, I guess that solved it- I had run that exact line of code yesterday evening with no result.